# Multiples extensions for one component

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I have the following installer:

```
        var endPoint = WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration("IExternalService");

        //Add Authentication Token
        endPoint.AddExtensions(new ExternalServiceEndpointBehavior());

        container.Register(
        Component
            .For<IExternalService>()
            .AsWcfClient(DefaultClientModel.On(endPoint))
            .LifestylePerWcfOperation()
        );
```

How can I register the same service but with a different extension, to be solved only in certain places?